# Bash - Process file with null bytes

Tags: bash, encoding, null

I have a file with special encoding that contains null bytes in multiple places.
I would like to load the entire content of this file into an environment variable.

- Trying to load it using echo, like in: `var=$(<./file)` ignores null bytes & breaks encoding
- xxd and similar, like `var=$(xxd ./file)` will stop reading the file on the first occurrence of the null byte.

This is of course because they cannot distinguish between this case, and an end of input.
What workaround / encoding can be used to load the content of this file into an environment variable?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: thanks @Cyrus for the warm welcome and the request for clarification! Was sure it was clear from the description, added some script samples.

Comment: `$(xxd ./file) will stop reading the file on the first occurrence of the null byte.` This is not possible. If that happens, it means your `xxd` is broken. If it really happens, please post an [MCVE], on my system `printf "%02x" $(seq -f "%.0f" 0 255) | xxd -r -p | xxd -p` prints all possible bytes. My answer to your question would be: use `xxd -p`.

Comment: `var=$(xxd /bin/ls); echo "$var" | xxd -r | cmp /bin/ls -` confirms that a 130k binary file with plenty of null bytes is not corrupted by this process

Comment: Base64 encoding is a little more space-efficient than hex, and also works for this: `var=$(base64 /bin/ls); echo "$var" | base64 -d | cmp /bin/ls -`

Comment: if you prefer to assign a continuous hex string to your variable, look at `var=$(xxd -p /bin/ls | tr -d '\n'); echo "$var" | xxd -p -r | cmp /bin/ls -`

Comment: My mistake!! forgot to surround $var with quotes! Thanks allot for pointing out @KamilCuk and @'that other guy'